# C: printf() and putchar() questions

Tags: c, input, printf, user-input, putchar

I was reading K&R book and wanted to test out printf() and putchar() functions in ways that I never tried. I encountered several unexpected events and would like to hear from more experienced programmers why that happens.

```
char c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
//put char(c);
    printf("%d your character was.\n", c);
}
```

1. How would one get EOF (end of file) in the input stream (getchar() or scanf() functions)? Unexpected key that is not recognized by getchar()/scanf() function could produce it?
2. In my book, it says that c has to be an integer, because it needs to store EOF and the variable has to be big enough to hold any possible char that EOF can hold. This doesn't make sense for me, because EOF is a constant integer with a value of -1, which even char can store. Can anyone clarify what was meant by this?
3. What happens when I send "hello" or 'hello' to putchar() function? It expects to get an integer, but returns weird output, such as *EE* or *oo*, if I send the latter string or char sequence.
4. Why when I use printf() function that is written above I get two outputs? One is the one I entered and the other one is integer, which in ASCII is end of line. Does it produce the second output, because I press enter, which it assumes to be the second character?

Thanks.

Comment: `EOF` usually is "-1", `getchar()` returns it when `read()` from terminal returns 0. You can't use `char` for `getchar` because then in case of printing character with code 255 (for example, 'Ъ' in KOI8-R) you'll get a false `EOF`. To hide input characters you should properly setup your terminal (turn off echo).

Comment: by saying false `EOF`, you mean that the character is an integer larger than 1 byte and can be recognized by getchar(), if the variable's range is set to be more than 1 byte?

Comment: `'hello'` is not a valid string, it possibly results in undefined behaviour. Something between `''` must only represent a single character.

Comment: By saying "false EOF" I mean that you enter a character but your application will think that that is EOF. Any letter == unsigned char, so, you need at least 2 bytes to send EOF!

Comment: I agree that any letter is an unsigned char, but char's range is also negative numbers. How is it that `EOF` need 2 bytes if it's -1? What characters can a person input to make the application think that it's `EOF`?

Comment: If your current codepage is 1252 (the default on most Western cultures), typing ÿ (LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS, whose value is 255 in this codepage) will cause such a fake EOF. Because `(signed char)255 == (signed char)-1` is true.

Comment: `getchar()` will returns you any possible `char`, which means any value from 0 to 255 (if unsigned). But in case of error, it needs to give you an error code, so `getchar()` must return at least 257 different values, `char` is a type unable to distinguish between more than 256 values. So you need a wider type. For historical reasons, `short` wasn't appropriate (not sure of being more than a byte long), then `int` was chosen (sure of being long enough). So technically `getchar()` returns 0-255 in case of a real char being read, and -1 in case of error. You must distinguish between -1 and 255.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. on Linux, you can send it with Ctrl+d
2. you need an int, otherwise you can't make the difference between EOF and the last possible character (0xFFFF is not the same than 0x00FF)
3. `putchar` wants a character, not a string, if you're trying to give it a string, it'll print a part of the string address
4. you only get one output: the ascii value of the character you entered, the other "input" is what you typed in the terminal

**edit - more details about 2**

You need an int, because getchar can returns both a character of value -1 (0x00FF) and an integer of value -1 (0xFFFF), they don't have the same meaning: the character of value -1 is a valid character (for instance, it's ÿ in latin-1) while the integer of value -1 is EOF in this context.

Here's a simple program that shows the difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    {
        char c = 0xFF; /* this is a valid char */
        if (c == EOF) printf("wrong end of file detection\n");
    }
    {
        int c = 0xFF; /* this is a valid char */
        if (c == EOF) printf("wrong end of file detection\n");
    }
}
```

The first test succeeds because 0xFF == -1 for char, while the second tests fails because 0x00FF != -1 for int.

I hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: and on Windows, EOF is Ctrl+Z

Comment: Thanks. I would like the second point to be more explained. Do you mean that there are characters larger than 0x00FF (1 byte), and if we use a char, it cannot recognize those characters?

Comment: @decas, when working with `char` functions, there are no characters larger than 0x000000FF, except for EOF which is 0xFFFFFFFF on a 32-bit platform. The problem comes from the fact that `(char)0x000000FF` and `(char)0xFFFFFFFF` have the same value: `0xFF` alias `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

1. you must close the input stream to get EOF. Usually with CTRL-D in UNIX, but see you tty config (stty -a)
2. already answered
3. same
4. your tty echoes what you type by default. If you don't want this, set it in noecho mode (stty -echo). Becareful as some shells sets it again to echo. Try with sh. You must be aware taht tty also buffers your inputs until RETURN is types (see stty manual for raw mode if you need).